# Converting Int to char * and displaying on screen

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-ttf

When I draw on the screen I want to show a dynamic text area for the game score. The only problem is that when I redraw the screen, it is not updated with the new score value and also there is garbled characters that appear after the zero. What I am trying to do is store an int that keeps the players score and increment that int and redraw the new value on the screen.

```
void drawText(SDL_Surface* screen,
char* string,
int posX, int posY)
{
TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("ARIAL.TTF", 40);

SDL_Color foregroundColor = { 255, 255, 255 };
SDL_Color backgroundColor = { 0, 0, 0 };

SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(font, string,
    foregroundColor, backgroundColor);

SDL_Rect textLocation = { posX, posY, 0, 0 };

SDL_BlitSurface(textSurface, NULL, screen, &textLocation);

SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);

TTF_CloseFont(font);
}

char convertInt(int number)
{
stringstream ss;//create a stringstream
ss << number;//add number to the stream
std::string result =  ss.str();//return a string with the contents of the stream

const char * c = result.c_str();
return *c;
}

score = score + 1;
char scoreString = convertInt(score);
drawText(screen, &scoreString, 580, 15);
```

Comment: Please tell me why you -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the garbled output, it's because you use the single character you receive from `convertInt` as a string by using the address-of operator (`&`). The data in memory after that single character may contain anything, and most likely *not* the special string terminator character.

Why return a single character from the string? Use e.g. [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and return the whole `std::string`, or keep using the `std::stringstream` and return the string proper from that.

As for the number not being updated, it might be that you have a multi-digit number but you're only returning the first digit. Return the string, as I recommended above, and keep using `std::string` in the call to `drawText`, and it should probably work better.

---

As it seems you are not allowed to alter the `drawText` function, use something like this:

```
score++;
// Cast to `long long` because VC++ doesn't have all overloads yet
std::string scoreString = std::to_string(static_cast<long long>(score));
drawText(screen, scoreString.c_str(), 580, 15);
```

Comment: i need to return a char *. I don't really know how to do this. The method I am using takes char * as parameter and I can't change it.

Comment: @JonathanO, Does it take `char *` or `const char *`?

Comment: @JonathanO Return a `std::string` from `convertInt` (or used the mentioned `std::to_string` function) and call `drawText` with the string using `c_str`.

Comment: @JonathanO, Then you can copy it. Something like this is one thing that works in C++03: `std::vector<char> cstr(str.begin(), str.end()); func(&cstr[0]);`

Comment: std::to_string(score) This gives me an error saying Error 2 error C2668: 'std::to_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

Comment: @JonathanO What type is `score`? And what version of Visual C++ do you use?

Comment: Score is an int. But it can be a long. I dont know what version of c++ i have or how to change it

Comment: @JonathanO The `std::to_string` function should have an explicit overload for `int`. However, by reading Microsofts [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404875%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it seems to not be fully implemented yet. If you do an explicit cast to `long long` it should work, please see my updated answer.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR DOING THIS I REALLY NEEDED THIS!!